# Python-mode code navigation

Tags: python, python-mode

How can I navigate from an abstract class/method to the implementations of that class/method? Using the M-. I can jump to function definition but I can't find a way to easily find the implementation.

Comment: You mean something like `xref-find-references`? (which probably works best when using a language server via eglot or lsp-mode).

Comment: xref-find-references seems to find only references of that functions (calls to that function) but not implementations.